# "Probabile che sì" o "probabile di sì"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

Ho sempre pensato che si dicesse "probabile di sì", però utilizzando un software mi proof-reading mi ha suggerito che la forma corretta dovrebbe essere "probabile che sì". La cosa mi lascia un po' perplesso. Qual è la forma giusta?

Comment: Io *probablile che sì* non l'ho mai sentito, sei sicuro che il software abbia capito che si tratta di *sì* con l'accento e non di *probablile che si*, come ad esempio nella frase *è probabile che si faccia confusione tra etc. etc.*? Prova a chiedere al software *probabile di no*.

Comment: Non sono sicuro di aver capito bene. Puoi fare un esempio di una frase in cui potrebbe comparire una di queste espressioni?